# Use remote keyboard and mouse to control local display on X Window System

Tags: x11

I have two computers running Linux, I need to use the mouse and keyboard but just the mouse and keyboard with the X Session from the other computer. I want to avoid the use of networking for transmiting video, just the mouse and keyboards.

Do you know if is this possible ?

Comment: Do you mean something like `synergy` ?

Comment: yes I mean something like synergy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RalphRönnquist mentions in a comment, this can be achieved using `synergy`:

```
sudo apt-get install synergy
```

It should be installed on both computers, then the computer *to be controlled* runs the client (`synergyc`), and the computer which should share its keyboard/mouse starts synergy server, which then has to be configured (via a GUI) to let the client computer to connect, and define where the area occupied by the remote screen is located on the extended desktop.

There are comprehensive guides explaining the process in details, e.g. [this one](https://www.radishlogic.com/raspberry-pi/use-synergy-raspberry-pi/) for a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Not available in Debian Stable :(